# What are continuous deformations of surfaces called?

Tags: algebraic-topology, terminology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory

Below is my sketch of the deformation of the top hemisphere (of a ball) into the lower hemisphere to give some intuition of what I am referring to.

**What is the name for a continuous deformation of surfaces?**

I want to say something like "2-homotopy" or "surface homotopy" or "homotopy of homotopies" -- although perhaps it should be a "3-homotopy" since it corresponds to a continuous map from $[0,1]^3$ or $B^3$ into the space $X$ (singular $3-$simplex), its image in non-degenerate/singular cases would be 3-dimensional, and [it corresponds to $3-$morphisms in higher category theory](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/homotopy/homotopy.pdf) -- of course that would make homotopies "2-homotopies", so maybe "3-path" would be a better term.

Anyway it would be nice to be able to say something like "the second homology group of the ball $B^3$ is trvial whereas that of the sphere $S^2$ is not, since there exists a 2-homotopy between the top and bottom hemispheres passing through the ball $B^3$". I.e. to extend to higher dimensions [the description of the generators of 1-boundaries as closed paths enclosing homotopies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2010581/what-is-the-geometric-motivation-for-quotienting-out-boundaries-in-homology/2010849#comment4128747_2010849).

**EDIT:** [This page on nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+2-type) seems relevant.

[image]

Comment: You're simply talking about a usual homotopy between two embeddings of a surface, (in your example, you have $h:S^2\times [0,1]$) perhaps with the added requirement that $h(\cdot,t)$ is an embedding for all $t\in [0,1]$, which would make it an [isotopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy#Isotopy). It is important to note that what you are doing really is nothing like what one should call a "2-homotopy", because you're just varying *one* parameter.

Comment: @Danu Thank you for clarifying this for me -- I didn't know. So a homotopy doesn't have to be between two curves, it can also be between two surfaces? I thought having trivial $n-$dimensional homology didn't imply having trivial fundamental group, e.g. the Poincare sphere has the same homology as the regular sphere but non-trivial fundamental group (while the regular sphere does have trivial fundamental group). Do $n$-boundaries enclose homotopies of singular $n-$simplices?

Comment: You would do well to look up the definition of a homotopy. You will see that it is defined as an equivalence of maps between fixed spaces. If you're talking about two surfaces being homotopic, what you really (should) mean is that the corresponding inclusion maps are homotopic. This of course makes sense for curves, surfaces etc. This does not imply any relations between homotopy groups.

Comment: @Danu Your point is correct and something I had not realized or appreciated before. Specifically when I say "homotopy" I mean "homotopy of paths", which I think is the only type of homotopy used in defining the fundamental group. However now that I think about I have seen the term used more generally and have not been distinguishing in my mind. Now of course I am confused as to what "homotopically trivial" is supposed to mean then but that would best be left for another question. Anyway, so the answer to my question is basically "a homotopy between two singular 2-simplices" it seems.